# SockitIO keep getting blocked by cors policy

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I'm keep getting this error in my app (nodeJs as API) and agnualr8 as Frontend
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQJpoTm' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

server code:

```
 const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
cors: {
  origin: config.ui_host,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
},
```

});

and here is the angular code :

```
 this.socket = io(socketEndpoint,
  {
    transportOptions: {
      polling: {
        extraHeaders: {
          'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')),
          'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Authorization',
          // 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
          // 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        }
      }
    },
  }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

1-control the method you are calling (is not an header problem but a server conf) you have enable only get and post (i think you are calling a get anyway)
2-try to clear node cache
3- control the value of origin.ui_host is really loacalhost:4200

Comment: the same code was working previously fine, i got this error after updating some node modules